# Install Microsoft Patches with Powershell

Tags: installation, powershell-2.0, windows-update

I am writing a script to install patches on Windows boxes. The best methodology I can find is to:

1) map a network drive
2) copy files over
3) install files
4) clean up and log
5) remove network drive

I can do all this except for number 3. How do I install/execute a file remotely via powershell? I want to avoid using PSEXEC; I'd like to use all that powershell has to offer.

Also, Is there a better way than I am seeing? I'd like to eventually expand this into something that would audit and see which patches are installed.

Comment: Not sure, I am thinking:

    invoke-command -computerName $computer -scriptBlock{invoke-item $path}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

invoke-item/invoke-command should work (depending upon how the patches are packaged) as long as you have remoting enabled.

However, it seems like you're trying to devise a solution to an already-solved problem in your last paragraph. [WSUS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb332157.aspx) & [SCCM](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/system-center/configuration-manager-2012.aspx) (or System Center, as they're calling it now) are designed to do exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: I understand. I am to find a solution without using wsus & sccm. For whatever reason they want multiple backups...

Comment: Nothing yet, I think I'll accept this one as it is the closest.